# What does this line of code mean in maximising a normal likelihood function?

Tags: r

I am learning R programming and learning how to write functions in R. Below is the piece of code in which I am unable to understand the 4th line i.e. params[!fixed] <- p .

```
make.NegLogLik <- function(data, fixed=c(FALSE,FALSE)) { 
    params <- fixed
    function(p) { 
    params[!fixed] <- p
        mu <- params[1]
        sigma <- params[2]
        a <- -0.5*length(data)*log(2*pi*sigma^2) 
        b <- -0.5*sum((data-mu)^2) / (sigma^2) 
        -(a+b)
    }
}

set.seed(1); 
normals <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)
nLL <- make.NegLogLik(normals)
nLL


optim(c(mu = 0, sigma = 1), nLL)$par


nLL <- make.NegLogLik(normals, c(FALSE, 2))  
optimize(nLL, c(-1, 3))$minimum`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
fixed = c(FALSE, FALSE)

params <- fixed
params
params[!fixed]

[1] FALSE FALSE
```

Initially you just pass a vector with two boolean values.

```
fixed = c(FALSE, 2)

params <- fixed
params
params[!fixed]

!fixed

> params
[1] 0 2
> params[!fixed]
[1] 0
```

But when you give your function an argument, you see that there is no `FALSE`. This is because of something called coercion. `FALSE` gets coerced to 0.

So what now happens is this: You get the the element of params, which is NOT the second element in your vector, which is 0.

Normal indexing like this: `c(1,2,3)[2]`

Comment: if you like my answer, please accept and or upvote it :-)